# Setting an image as a collection Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to just put an image as a collection view cell, pretty much. No fancy stuff, just the image itself, and, well, at least resized to the cell size.

What I am doing doesn't even compile, even though I feel pretty confident.

Context : 
The collection view is a list of sports, with the required image. The cell actually holds an image and a string (the title of the sport), and is a segue to another page. I don't need this specific page to be dynamic,  i'll actually type all the sports and put the images myself, as i don't need too  many and it will  no be edited, ever.

The collection view is called typeCollection and is in the .h (hence the _ in the code)
MyEvent.typePictures is the 'Event' object  holding the array of images 'typePictures'.

This is my array of pictures in the Event class :

```
    _typePictures = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"climbing.jpg"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"skydiving.jpg"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"running.jpg"], 
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"swimming.jpg"],
                                          nil];
```

And this is my cell creation method in my controller :

```
    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [_typeCollection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[_MyEvent.typePictures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    cell.backgroundView = imageView;


    return cell;

}
```

It stops compiling at the `UIImage *image` line and gives this error in the log :

> -[UIImage pathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa4b4440 2014-05-30 13:55:55.344 ApiSport[2580:60b] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UIImage pathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0xa4b4440'

Also, if I remove the 3 lines above my `return cell;`, everything compiles just fine but i obviously don't have my image shown ( i just have the basic pink background i had setup manually)

I hope i gave enough explanation ! This is what i'm looking for

- Why it isn't working
- What i should do to make it work, if possible with a small explanation

Thank you a lot for your time :)

Comment: It didn't not compile.  You can't get exceptions thrown if the code didn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

To get the correct image you simply need

> UIImage *image = _typePictures[indexPath.row];